# where AsyncPageTask thread are created in asp.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

I know AsyncPageTask creates a thread which we can use for long running processes, i was wondering where this thread is created as i am sure it does not use IIS request processing thread,  then where this thread exist ? 
please can someone explain ? thanks in advance

Comment: IIS does not create threads for ASP.NET. ASP.NET does.

Comment: thanks, u mean for every aspx page request... asp.net internally create a thread ? i thot iis worker process do this work

Comment: What  you call the IIS worker process is part of ASP.NET, not part of IIS. I believe that requests normally arrive on thread pool threads from I/O completion ports. "IIS" does relatively little once the App Pool is started.

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you, as a basic courtesy to others...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thread used for your long running process comes from I/O thread pool (request thread is then returned to the request thread pool). When all your `PageAsyncTasks` finish, ASP.Net gets back a request thread from the request thread pool.

So the workflow is basically this: request thread -> any number of I/O threads -> request thread.